# Hide terminal prompt while greetings is typed in jquery terminal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-terminal

I am using [Jquery Terminal](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/api_reference.php), and am trying to hide the prompt until greetings is typed. Currently I am using setTimeout to delay greeting but later will stimulate user typing. Using set_prompt() I am able to hide text in prompt but cursor still keeps in blinking. Here is my js code

```
$('#term_demo').terminal({
echo: function(arg1) {
    this.echo(arg1);
},
rpc: 'some_file.php',
calc: {
    add: function(a, b) {
        this.echo(a+b);
    },
    sub: function(a, b) {
        this.echo(a-b);
    }
}
}, { prompt: '>', greeting: false, onInit : function(){
var that  = this;
this.set_prompt("");
setTimeout(function(){
    that.echo("gugrgv");
},3000);

} });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pause to hide both prompt and disable blinking and if you will want to have animation using prompt you can use `pause(true)`. It will pause, but not hide the prompt so use:

```
var prompt = term.get_prompt();
term.set_prompt('').pause(true)
setTimeout(function(){
    that.echo("gugrgv").set_prompt(prompt).resume();
}, 3000);
```

And if you want simulate typing you can check [typing example](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php#user-typing)